# JavaFx StackedBar Chart Issue

Tags: javafx-2

I have a chart with data stacked on (-,+)Y-Axis.

- With JfreeChart all this go rigth and data appear perfectly on each bar without loss. [image]
- But when using javafx StackedBar Chart , when bar series have (positive & negative) data  stacked bar corrupted and loss data.
  [image]

  ```
              if (plusValue > 0) {
                  series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(xPoint, plusValue));
              }
              if (minusValue > 0) {
                  series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(xPoint, -minusValue));
              }
  ```

Update :

-[Oracle StackedBarChart Sample](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/bar-chart.htm)
- "I change Series value"

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.StackedBarChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class StackedBarChartSample extends Application {

final static String austria = "Austria";
final static String brazil = "Brazil";
final static String france = "France";
final static String italy = "Italy";
final static String usa = "USA";
final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
final StackedBarChart<String, Number> sbc =
        new StackedBarChart<String, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);
final XYChart.Series<String, Number> series1 =
        new XYChart.Series<String, Number>();
final XYChart.Series<String, Number> series2 =
        new XYChart.Series<String, Number>();
final XYChart.Series<String, Number> series3 =
        new XYChart.Series<String, Number>();

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    stage.setTitle("Bar Chart Sample");
    sbc.setTitle("Country Summary");
    xAxis.setLabel("Country");
    xAxis.setCategories(FXCollections.<String>observableArrayList(
            Arrays.asList(austria, brazil, france, italy, usa)));
    yAxis.setLabel("Value");
    series1.setName("2003");
    // plus value
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(austria, 200));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(brazil, 300));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(france, 400));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(italy, 500));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(usa, 600));
    // minus value
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(austria, -200));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(brazil, -300));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(france, -400));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(italy, -500));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(usa, -600));
    series2.setName("2004");
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(austria, 200));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(brazil, 300));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(france, 400));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(italy, 500));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(usa, 600));
    // minus value
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(austria, -200));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(brazil, -300));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(france, -400));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(italy, -500));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(usa, -600));
    series3.setName("2005");
    series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(austria, 200));
    series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(brazil, 300));
    series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(france, 400));
    series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(italy, 500));
    series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(usa, 600));
    // minus value
    series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(austria, -200));
    series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(brazil, -300));
    series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(france, -400));
    series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(italy, -500));
    series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(usa, -600));
    Scene scene = new Scene(sbc, 800, 600);
    sbc.getData().addAll(series1, series2, series3);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

- Without minus value.
  [image: Without minus value]
- With minus value data corrupted.
  [image: With minus value data corrupted]

Comment: Which version of JFX do you use?

Comment: @Alexander Kirov java version "1.7.0_11"

Comment: Can you file an issue on controls component of JavaFX in jira?

Comment: I've checked, and seems, there is no such issue yet. You will have to add a piece of code with according piece of data. If you cannot - I need your code and data, to file the issue

Comment: @Alexander Kirov java version "1.7.0_11", javafx.runtime.version: 2.2.4-b19

Comment: This issue is unlikely to be fixed now, so it needs to be filed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the bug on the StackedBarChart code:

```
    private Map<Series, Map<String,Data<X, Y>>> seriesCategoryMap = new HashMap<Series, Map<String, Data<X, Y>>>();
```

- That Line of code mean that each series has `map<String categoryPoint ,data bar>`,so that series has only `one bar for that categoryPoint`, and that bar will be the last value putted  into map as map will clear previous bar data.

  ```
  categoryMap.put(categoryPoint,bar);
  ```
- But we need for each series in seriesCategoryMap to have categoryMap But that map must have `for each categoryPoint to be List<Data>`.
- Conclusions, for each series we have categoryMap and for each categoryPoint in that categoryMap we have `List<Data<X,Y>> bar List to have positive and negative bars`.
- So that line of code become.

  ```
  private Map<Series, Map<String, List<Data<X, Y>>>> seriesCategoryMap = new HashMap<Series, Map<String, List<Data<X, Y>>>>();
  ```
- After that we have to update the code depend on that data Structure.

**1-Update 'dataItemAdded & seriesAdded' methods.**

```
        // list to hold more that one bar "positive and negative"
    List<Data<X, Y>> itemList = categoryMap.get(category) != null ? categoryMap.get(category) : new ArrayList<Data<X, Y>>();
    itemList.add(item);
    categoryMap.put(category, itemList);
```

**2-getDataItem method.**

```
    private List<Data<X, Y>> getDataItem(Series<X, Y> series, int seriesIndex, int itemIndex, String category) {
    Map<String, List<Data<X, Y>>> catmap = seriesCategoryMap.get(series);
    return catmap != null ? catmap.get(category) != null ? catmap.get(category) : new ArrayList<Data<X, Y>>() : new ArrayList<Data<X, Y>>();
}
```

**3-updateAxisRange & layoutPlotChildren update that two method to manage bar length over negative and positive values axis.**

- [Updated code for StackedBarChart](https://gist.github.com/KhaledLela/5190333)
- [Oracle StackedBarChart Sample with positive and negative bars](https://gist.github.com/KhaledLela/5190378)
- **StackedBarChart show bar perfectly without any data corruption** [image: StackedBarChart show bar perfectly without any data corruption]

Comment: Khaled, did you file an issue in jira?

Comment: @AlexanderKirov Is the above bug report correctly filled ? if not you can kindly fill the bug report by the data on the above line. to be fixed in the next release and then tell me to remove my report.

Answer (score -1):

Use...

http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/2.2/samples/Ensemble/index.html

or

[JavaFX Scene Builder 1.1](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/devpreview-1429449.html)

[image]