# javaFX's StackedBarGraph with Values Between 0.0 and 1.0 only uses most recently added series

Tags: java, charts, javafx

javaFX's StackedBarGraph with Values Between 0.0 and 1.0 will only use the most recently added series. For some reason it forgets about the previously added series. I how do I fix it?

Should look like (paying attention to the relative scale and not the actual values):

[image]

But actually looks like:

[image]

Sample code from Oracle's website (https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/bar-chart.htm) modified to use values between 0.0 and 1.0:

```
package main;

import java.util.Arrays;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.StackedBarChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application {

    final static String austria = "Austria";
    final static String brazil = "Brazil";
    final static String france = "France";
    final static String italy = "Italy";
    final static String usa = "USA";
    final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
    final StackedBarChart<String, Number> sbc = new StackedBarChart<String, Number>(
            xAxis, yAxis);
    final XYChart.Series<String, Number> series1 = new XYChart.Series<String, Number>();
    final XYChart.Series<String, Number> series2 = new XYChart.Series<String, Number>();
    final XYChart.Series<String, Number> series3 = new XYChart.Series<String, Number>();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Bar Chart Sample");
        sbc.setTitle("Country Summary");
        xAxis.setLabel("Country");
        xAxis.setCategories(FXCollections.<String> observableArrayList(Arrays.asList(austria, brazil, france, italy, usa)));
        yAxis.setLabel("Value");
        series1.setName("2003");
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(austria, 0.02560134));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(brazil,  0.02014882));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(france,  0.01000000));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(italy,   0.03540715));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(usa,     0.01200000));
        series2.setName("2004");
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(austria, 0.05740185));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(brazil,  0.04194119));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(france,  0.04526337));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(italy,   0.11732016));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(usa,     0.01484527));
        series3.setName("2005");
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(austria, 0.4500065));
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(brazil,  0.4483576));
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(france,  0.1872218));
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(italy,   0.1755731));
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(usa,     0.9263368));
        Scene scene = new Scene(sbc, 800, 600);
        sbc.getData().addAll(series1, series2, series3);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this problem is related to: [JavaFx StackedBar Chart Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410153/javafx-stackedbar-chart-issue)

The fix from that article also works for this problem. Unfortunately, the fix involves importing one of Oracle's private packages which would limit the portability of the solution.

In that post the issue was with negative values. In my post the values are between 0.0 and 1.0.